# Why LASSO selects intercept only?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, lasso-regression

I am doing a projects using `glmnet` package and have hard time to interpret the result.

The scenario as follows.

There are 7 variables `x1`, ..., `x7`.
`x3`, ... , `x7` are scaled to mean 0 and std 1.

I fit a Lasso regression on `x3`, ... , `x7`. Lasso selects some variables.

Then I fit a Lasso regression on all variables, i.e., `x1`, ..., `x7`, Lasso selects intercept only.

I do not know why this happened and how to fix it.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But this sounds more like a model fitting question would might be appropriate for [stats.se].

Comment: The selection is conditional on a specific value for the penalty. Are you using the same value for the two setups?

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your advice.  I post the same question to cross validated.

Comment: @ekstroem No. I used cv.glmnet to fit model, then used lambda.1se to get the estimation of the coefficients. The lambdas chosen are different in the two models.

Comment: i think your answer might be here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319861/how-to-interpret-lasso-shrinking-all-coefficients-to-0